# Installing for new account getting error addin admin

Tags: installation

./magento admin:user:create     ( used temp pass for purpose of post )

```
#0 /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate.php(98): Zend_Validate_StringLength->isValid('$omeP##')
#1 /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/DataObject.php(72): Zend_Validate->isValid('$omeP##')
#2 /home/juneusa/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/AdminUserCreateCommand.php(91): Magento\Framework\Validator\DataObject->isValid(Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject))
#3 /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php(384): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\AdminUserCreateCommand->Magento\Setup\Console\Command\{closure}('$omeP##')
#4 /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php(81): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->validateAttempts(Object(Closure), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput), Object(Symfony\Co in /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate/StringLength.php on line 248
```

Comment: which version you installed magento 2 ?

Comment: Magento-CE-2.3.0-2018-11-27-10-23-08  is what I got

Comment: please check all requirement of magento v2.3.0 - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: fronend is ready to work without anyerror.
you to create admin user you get error right?

Comment: Orginally: used the following .

/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1

Comment: please try to this command - php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin1" --admin-password="admin123*" --admin-email="admin123@gmail.com" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="dev"

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function iconv_strlen() in /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php:1823
Stack trace:
#0 /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate/EmailAddress.php(501): Zend_Validate_Hostname->isValid('gmail.com')

Comment: #1 /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate/EmailAddress.php(560): Zend_Validate_EmailAddress->_validateHostnamePart()
#2 /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/DataObject.php(7

Comment: 2): Zend_Validate_EmailAddress->isValid('admin123@gmail....')
#3 /home/juneusa/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/AdminUserCreateCommand.php(239): Magento\Framework\Validator\DataObject->isValid(Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject))
#4 /home/juneusa/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/AdminUserCreateCommand.php(158): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\AdminUserCreateCommand->validate(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput))
#5 /home/juneusa/mage in /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php on line 1823

Comment: PHP 7.1.27 currently enabled

Comment: please install iconv php extenstion

Comment: Go to php.ini and check for extension=iconv.so in your server.

Comment: and the result is ...
Created Magento administrator user named admin1

When cPanel added the php 7.1, 7.2 it was missing..   Let`s see if it works now

Comment: Hiren, Account Creation is working now,  added iconv and php.ini confirmed.

Comment: #0 /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php(28): Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle->cleanLocale('en_US')
#1 /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Lists.php(92): Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle->get('en_US')
#2 /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/Locale.php(42): Magento\Framework\Setup\Lists->getLocaleList()
#3 /home/juneusa/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/InstallStoreConfigurationCommand.php(321): Magento\Framework\Validator\Locale->isValid('en_US')

Comment: #4 /home/juneusa/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/InstallStoreConfigurationCommand.php(241): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallStoreConfigurationCommand->validateCodes(Object(Magento\Framework\Validator\Locale), 'en_US', 'language')
#5 /home/juneusa/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/Inst in /home/juneusa/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php on line 64

Comment: Added Intl extention  .. Next error

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'magento'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

In InstallCommand.php line 264:

  Parameter validation failed

Comment: please check all extesnion bc-math , ctype , curl , dom , gd , intl , mbstring , hash , openssl , PDO/MySQL , SimpleXML, soap, spl, libxml, xsl, zip, json, iconv

Comment: is database config error - Next error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied 
please check your database.

Comment: please also check extesntion bash , gzip , lsof , mysql , mysqldump , nice , php , sed , tar

Comment: Rechecking extentions now, and got the correct info for DB.  Standby

Comment: The Install has started, Thank you for assisting, yes I should have pushed the Precheck harder.    All the issues were related to PHP extensions

 HIren, excellent troubleshooting

Comment: Says install completed,  /admin_is74o3    I did the export=  earlier.  did I missing something else?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91193/discussion-on-question-by-william-jensen-installing-for-new-account-getting-erro).